# Viewing/ executing a XML file with a python script

Tags: python, xml

I have a program, that generates XML files out of CSV files. I am doing this with a Gui on tkinter. I am still very new to python and programming in it self.
So here is my question. I have a function, that gets the filepath of the last created xml file in a special directory. Now I want to add a button to my program that allows me to view/ execute this file in my webbrowser after I clicked it.

Here is a example of what i got so far:

```
import os
import glob
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
def get_filename():
    filename = max(glob.iglob("C:/Users/klaus/Desktop/XML Converter (1)/Python Converter/*.xml"),key=os.path.getmtime)
    exec(open(filename).read())
    print(filename)
clicker = tkinter.Button(root,text = "Click me",command = get_filename)
clicker.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does it mean to "execute" an xml file?

Comment: Perhaps the `webbrowser` module is what you are looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: If you have a CSV file and you click on it. It opens in your default web browser and shows you the content. I want to generate this action with a bit of code on python @JonSG